# PHP: sql insert not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using PHP jQuery and Mysql for creating updates in admin panel which will appear on users updates page. All my other forms are working properly but only this updates section is not working properly. The problem is the values are not getting inserted in database. I have added my jQuery and PHP code below:

Here is my add_update.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["update"]))
{
    include("config.php");
    $update=$_POST["update"];
    $type=$_POST["type"];
    $date=date("d/m/Y");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO updates (update, type, date) VALUES ('$update', '$type', '$date')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "404 - Page Not Found";
}
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#update_submit").click(function(){
        var update=$("#update").val();
        var type=$("#update_type").val();
        if (update.length<3)
        {
            alert("Update Invalid");
            $("#update").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            var postData="update="+update+"&type="+type;
            $.ajax({
                url: "add_update.php",
                data: postData,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="success"){
                        alert("Successfully added");
                        $.ajax({url: "updates_table.php", success: function(data){$(".update_table").html(data);}}); //This is just loading all the values from Database
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong! Please Try Again Later!");    
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I tried to see if my values are sent properly and if the sql was correct. They seem to be fine for me. Here is the sql code executed.

```
INSERT INTO updates (update, type, date) VALUES ('Some text', 'Info', '5/10/2015')
```

Take a look at my mysql table too:

```
CREATE TABLE `updates` (
`id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
`update` text,
`type` varchar(30),
`date` varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: probably need to put backticks ( ` ) around `date` in your insert. execute the sql code from sqladmin and post the error message also

Comment: @amdixon: The backticks are not working

Comment: and what message does sqladmin give when you execute the exact query

Comment: Update is a reserved word. Also, see prepared statements

Comment: @amdixon: Thank you so much, changing update to updates worked.

Comment: @amdixon: Add this as an answer, so that i can select it as worked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes applied**

> - For reserved words which you want to use for your fieldnames or tablenames, you need to use backticks around them like :

**updated query**

```
INSERT INTO `updates` (`update`, type, `date`) 
VALUES ('Some text', 'Info', '5/10/2015')
;
```

**Note**: technically the backticks are not required around the `date` fieldname or the `updates` tablename. They are required around `update`

Answer (score 1):

use the

```
mysqli_error()
```

and

```
mysqli_connect_error()
```

functions to retrieve the error that happened during your connecting to mysql / executing the insert statement

and try to put the

```
update
```

column name like this

```
`update`
```

Comment: I get this error:
Error description: Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 'update, type, date) VALUES ('Matrix Updated', 'Info', '10/05/2015')' � la ligne 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#update_submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will stop form from submitting and refreshing the page

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: How is that supposed to help me from my problem?

Comment: @Manikiran I think the form is submitted and refreshed before `ajax` is completed.